# How to increase the space of a segments in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, stack, segment, emu8086

I am currently doing some stuff with assembly x86, using emu8086, anyways i want to create a big stack but i see that when you define a new segment that you can use as stack it does not give it as much space as i need. So is there a way for me to define a segment that i can use for stack but to be able to store a lot of values in it?

Comment: What operating system are you programming for? On DOS with a COM executable, you can just grab whatever segment there is above you.

Comment: Stack size is limited to 64kb (the extent of any given real mode segment in physical memory) without creating your own stack routines.

Comment: @fuz : EMU8086 is a an 8086 emulator that contains a DOS like clone (not complete) with integrated debugger and assembler. It does support COM programs as well as EXE.

Comment: I Just use the emulator, because i am on a x64 system

Comment: Why don't you write some example, what size doesn't work for you? Do you realize, that segments in x86-16 are 64kiB limited (hard way)? So there shouldn't be any major problem to create COM program just using one of the full 64kiB segments above as stack. Hard to say, what kind of problem you have without disclosing some more details.

Comment: You can create more than one stack.